# Why am I not getting different colors when calling a random color generator?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image: Same colors in the initial view]
[image: Different colors for cards out of initial view]

```kotlin
package com.example.randomgradient.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.randomgradient.R
import com.example.randomgradient.model.GradientData
import java.util.*

class ItemAdapter(private val dataset: List<GradientData>, private val context: Context)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private var rnd: Random = Random()

    private fun colorGen() : Int {
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256))
    }

    class ItemViewHolder(private val view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val gradientView : View = view.findViewById(R.id.gradientview)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        val drawable  = holder.gradientView.background as GradientDrawable
        drawable.colors = intArrayOf(colorGen(), colorGen())
        holder.gradientView.background = drawable
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataset.size
    }
}
```

I have this code which works with `RecyclerView` in `android_main.xml`

I created a function `colorGen()` which randomly produces colors. These colors are then given to a `Drawable` which generates a linear gradient using these colors. I have 6 cards which have the linear gradient as their background.

When the application is run, the cards which are in the view of the screen have the same colors. However, as I scroll, the cards which come into the view later, all have different colors.

Why do the cards in the initial view have the same color if I am calling `colorGen()` for each color assigned to the linear gradient?

Points to understand the code:

- `GradientData` is a `data class` as `data class GradientData(val startColor: Int, val endColor: Int) { }`
- Dataset is a `List<GradientData>`
- `R.id.gradientview` points to the card which has `GradientDrawable` as their background.
- `R.layout.list_item` points to the `.xml` file which has the layout for the above-mentioned card.

Comment: Look at `mutate` method on `GradientDrawable` - it's not clear if this applies: A mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.  `setColors` (or colors) has a similar statement.

Comment: @Andy thanks a lot! `mutate` helped me achieve what I wanted. And thanks for the explanation too!

What I didn't understand form your explanation is if drawables from the same resource share a common state, why do the drawables change color when I scroll, i.e., why do out of view drawables don't share the same state?